# android imageview not getting focus

Tags: android

Recently I designed a view. there is 2 framelayout inside one layout. first layout has a list view second layout has an imageview. Issue is any touch or click event will not get for imagevew.

Comment: touch or click event will not get for imagevew means?

Comment: It means I cant catch event when touch on it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Call [`setOnClickListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) on the ImageView.

Alternatively, use [ImageButton()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).